# Getting guid value by order by OR a group count in CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table like this:

```
category | guid    | date_create
---------+-----------------------
   A     | 5BC2... | 1513092309831
   A     | 6A1C... | 1513090067577
   B     | 92A2... | 1513089780272
```

I need to make a group by hour and keep the count of each group which I can make like

```
SELECT
MAX(guid),count(1) as count
    FROM feed f
    GROUP BY 
          category,
          DATEPART(YEAR, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01')),
          DATEPART(MONTH, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01')),
          DATEPART(DAY, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01')),
          DATEPART(HOUR, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01'))
```

My problem here lies in me needing the guid that is most recent (with higher date_create) and not a MIN() or MAX()...

I can get it using CTE but then I don't see a way of getting the group count.

Any idea?

Comment: What is your desired output based on the sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to get the most recent member of each group, and then use a correlated subquery in the main query to get the count of rows in the same group as that member.

Comment: Following your advise I managed to achieve the desired results with the code below.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Tab Alleman advice I made the following in CTE to achieve my desired results.

```
WITH f AS
(
     SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER
         (
             PARTITION BY userf, rowtype, DATEPART(YEAR, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01')),
      DATEPART(MONTH, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01')),
      DATEPART(DAY, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01')),
      DATEPART(HOUR, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01'))

             ORDER BY date_create desc
         ) AS Recency,
  count(*) over (PARTITION BY userf,rowtype, DATEPART(YEAR, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01')),
      DATEPART(MONTH, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01')),
      DATEPART(DAY, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01')),
      DATEPART(HOUR, dateadd(S, f.date_create / 1000, '1970-01-01'))) as cnt
     FROM feed f
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM (SELECT f.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category, f.date_create / (1000 * 60 * 60)) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category, f.date_create / (1000 * 60 * 60)
                                ORER BY f.date_create DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM feed f
     ) f
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Presumably, `date_create` is the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01.  The arithmetic expression is a simpler way to convert to hours.

Comment: And this produces a group count?